# Найти всё, что НЕ относится к шаблону(Регулярное выражение)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте!
Подсажите, можно ли составить такое регулярное выражение, которое будет исключать то, что прописано в шаблоне?
Нужно найти все строки, которые могут иметь ЛЮБЫЕ символы, КРОМЕ английских букв и цифр.

Например, `preg_match("/[^a-z,A-Z,0-9]/",$text)`- найдет все бувы и цифры, а нужно, наоборот найти всё что угодно, **кроме** `/[^a-z,A-Z,0-9]/`
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Указанный пример уже ищет всё, кроме выбранных диапазонов. ^ - отрицание диапазона.

Comment: Выражение `[^a-z,A-Z,0-9]` — наоборот [**не найдёт**](https://regex101.com/r/qG1zL9/1) все латинские буквы и цифры. Но если Вы уберёте символ `^`, то Ваш шаблон как раз [**находит**](https://regex101.com/r/qG1zL9/2) только латинские буквы и цифры.

Comment: И да, запятая не нужна в тексте, если она не требуется по задаче

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятыми отделять блоки не нужно ничего.
Последняя регулярка (`/[^a-z,A-Z,0-9]/`) почти верна, стоит только убрать запятые:
`/[^a-zA-Z\d]/` (`\d` - сокращение от `0-9`).
[См. тут.](http://regexr.com/3dcse)

**UPDATE:**

**@СашаЧерных** предложил такой вариант: `^[^A-Za-z0-9]+$` ([проверка](https://regex101.com/r/cE1yH1/4)).
Находит строки, которые полностью состоят из любых символов, кроме `a-z\d`.

Comment: Other, т. к. автору «Нужно найти все строки, которые могут иметь ЛЮБЫЕ символы, КРОМЕ английских букв и цифр.», предлагаю добавить в ответ шаблон, разрешающий данную задачу, — `^[^A-Za-z0-9]+$` — [**демонстрация**](https://regex101.com/r/cE1yH1/4), и/или посложнее, с использованием негативной опережающей проверки — `^(?:(?![A-Za-z0-9]).)*$` — [**демонстрация**](https://regex101.com/r/cE1yH1/3). Спасибо.

Comment: На счёт первой - согласен, хотя может у ТС строка "что-тоabcтут", найдёт две подстроки (если флаги указать). Задание не так хорошо прописано, чтобы гадать: какие строки, полностью ли они должны подходить под выражение или часть, сколько их и т. д. Ответили что могли. Автору, видимо, этого хватило. Вторая - зачем перегружать ядро, если и так работает? P. S. Текст проверки озадачил :)